# How can you pass JSON Object of option parameters to open a new window?

Tags: javascript, json, window.open

the window.open() object has some funky parameter list...

is there a way to do something like window.open({options..});

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such facility built-in to the language.

However, it's fairly easy to write one yourself.
For example:

```
function popup(url, name, options) {
    if (arguments.length === 2) {
        options = name;
        name = options.name;
    }

    var features = false;

    for (var key in options) {
        if (!options.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;
        if (key === "name") continue;

        if(features)
            features += ",";

        features += key + "=";

        if (!options[key])
            features += "no";
        else if (options[key] === true)
            features += "yes";
        else
            features += options[key];
    }
    return window.open(url, name, features);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could pass `options` as a URL parameter:

```
window.open( myURL + "/?options=" + JSON.stringify(options) );
```

Comment: You're misunderstanding the question.

Answer (score 2):

well

```
function newWindow(options) {
  var opts = [], keys = ['height', 'width', 'scrollable', /* all those options */];
  for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; ++i) {
    if (keys[i] in options)
      opts.push(keys[i] + '=' + options[keys[i]]);
  }
  return window.open(options.url, options.name, opts.join(','));
}
```

Comment: It would be cleaner to allow `yes` or `no` strings to be specified as booleans.

Comment: Yes I guess so; it was just a suggested approach.

Answer (score 1):

No. That is a dom function called with javascript.

In any case, the 'options object' strategy is really only coming into such great usage with the concept of JSON, which the DOM spec preceeds by some time.

You can build a JS object with fields for the parameters and override toString() if you want a window opener helper.

Answer (score 1):

No, but you could write your own wrapper easily enough.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so as the features are a comma separated list of window features

From **[MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.open)**

```
var WindowObjectReference = window.open(strUrl, 
                                        strWindowName  
                                        [, strWindowFeatures]);
```

There's nothing stopping you from writing a wrapper though that accepts an object and then calls `window.open()` with the appropriate arguments

Answer (score 1):

you could make your own function to parse a JSON object and call the window.open() function with specific params based on the parsing?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this doesn't exist.
The easiest solution would be to just convert it from json to the format used for the parameters.
Here's a simple way to do it in one line by using some global regular expressions:

```
JSON.stringify(properties).replace(/true/g, "yes").replace(/false/g, "no").replace(/:/g, '=').replace(/}|{|"/g, '');
```

This works for pretty much all browsers, I tested it in Internet Explorer 11 too.

A more modern approach is with replaceAll:

```
JSON.stringify(properties).replaceAll("true", "yes").replaceAll("false", "no").replaceAll(':', '=').replaceAll(/}|{|"/g, '');
```

This method has less browser support but it gives the same result.